# how to undo an iptables rule that I did?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, iptables

I accidentally did:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to 0.0.0.0
```

when `0.0.0.0` should be the server's IP address but I forgot to replace it. How can I undo this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just run:

```
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to 0.0.0.0
```

`-D` flag remove the rules that are matching the rule specified as parameters. In short, run the same command, but replace `-A` or `-I` with `-D` to remove that rule.